# insert geospatial datatype( mutipolygon) in mysql with java( jdbc)

Tags: java, jdbc, geospatial, geotools

I am using geotools library to extract the location information. With that I am getting an object of type

```
class com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon
```

I now want to store this field in my mysql table with a jdbc connection . 
When I directly try to insert it as
 `pstmtInsert.setObject(4, geoobject)` 
I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql can't know how to store your GEO object, or what is his size. You should not store the object the way you're trying.

The [PreparedStatement#setObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) documentation says :

> The JDBC specification specifies a standard mapping from Java Object types to SQL types. The given argument will be converted to the corresponding SQL type before being sent to the database. 
>   [...]
>   This method throws an exception if there is an ambiguity, for example, if the object is of a class implementing more than one of the interfaces named above.

Comment: Can you provide me the link where I can get the mapping from Java Objects to SQL types? I am trying to find that but was not able to find it for polygon/multipolygon.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

1. You need to convert the geometry object you have to well known text.  You'll find information on how to do that in the vividsolutions [API documentation](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#toText%28%29).

   ```
   geoobject.toText();
   ```
2. Insert / Update the data using the mysql [GeomFromText](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html) method.

   ```
   INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText(@g));
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It can be binary as well, e.g.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement
("INSERT INTO table (point, polygon) VALUES (PointFromWKB(?), GeomFromWKB(?))");

WKBWriter writer = new WKBWriter();

preparedStatement.setBytes(1, writer.write(point));
preparedStatement.setBytes(2, writer.write(polygon));

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```