# Mybatis mapper to Mysql Point object

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

I am working on a Spring boot server based on spatial functionalities.

And I am stuck by the mybatis match to customized object.

Now I have created table, and one column startLocation, which is a Point type.

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle`.`route` (
  `createtime` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatetime` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `startLocation` POINT NULL,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

And my Route java object is

```
@Table(name = "route")
public class Route extends Base {
    Point startLocation;

    public Location getStartLocation() {
        return startLocation;
    }

    public void setStartLocation(Location startLocation) {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
    }

   ....other fields
}
```

And my Location object just holds lat and long as double value.

```
package com.supplyplatform.pojo;

public class Location {
    double Lat;
    double Long;

    public double getLat() {
        return Lat;
    }
    public void setLat(double lat) {
        Lat = lat;
    }
    public double getLong() {
        return Long;
    }
    public void setLong(double l) {
        Long = l;
    }

}
```

My RouteMapper.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.supplyplatform.mapper.RouteMapper">
    <resultMap type = "com.supplyplatform.pojo.Route" id="Route">
        <id column="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="id" />
        <result column="startpoint" jdbcType="OTHER" property="startLocation" />
    </resultMap>

</mapper>
```

And it returns no typehandler exception.  `No typehandler found for property startLocation`
I have spent days on it. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I am trying to create association between the nested result map. The new xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.supplyplatform.mapper.RouteMapper">
    <select id="selectRoute" resultMap="Route">
        SELECT *, X(startpoint) as x, Y(startpoint) as y FROM vehicle.vc_route
    </select>
    <resultMap type = "com.supplyplatform.pojo.Route" id="Route">
        <id column="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="id" />
        <association property="startLocation" resultMap="Location" />
    </resultMap>
    <resultMap type = "com.supplyplatform.pojo.Location" id="Location">
        <result column="y" property="lat" />
        <result column="x" property="long" />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

But it always return no type handler exception for `Location startLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

Location is a complex type, then you have to specify how to map.

You can either decompose it as 2 simple type values: `SELECT ST_X(startPoint) as x, ST_Y(startpoint) as y` and then map an association:
Note that as specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239219/7076047) and in the [Mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html), you shall use st_x/st_y since x/y are deprecated from Mysql 5.7.6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.supplyplatform.mapper.RouteMapper">
    <resultMap type = "com.supplyplatform.pojo.Route" id="Route">
        <id column="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="id" />
        <association property="startLocation" resultMap="Location" />
    </resultMap>
    <resultMap type = "com.supplyplatform.pojo.Location" id="Location">
        <result column="y" property="lat" />
        <result column="x" property="long" />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

Or you can define a type handler:

```
public class PointTypeHandler extends org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler<Location> {

  Location getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) {
    Location location = new Location();
    Object point = rs.getObject(columnName);
    /* whatever is required to fill Location object */
    return location
  }
}
```

This is JDBC code, [this post may provide some clues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548114/insert-geospatial-datatype-mutipolygon-in-mysql-with-java-jdbc).

and reference it in the mapping:
`<result column="startpoint" jdbcType="OTHER" property="startLocation" typeHandler="PointTypeHandler"/>`

Comment: I am trying the nested resultMap approach but it always returns the No typehandler exception I have updated the question.

Comment: Do not `SELECT *` because the result set then contains a column named _startLocation_ and Mybatis tries to (auto)map it to the property _startLocation_ because column name matches property name.

Comment: so is it necessary to put "Location startpoint" as a field of Route object? The exception is always thrown from here.

Comment: You should eventually be able to fill your object keeping with this model. But you may try to move properties  lat, long into Route class (no more Location) as well as in the Route resultMap (no more association).

Comment: If you select * then the query returns (amongst all) a column _startLocation_ of type (Mysql) POINT, furthermore: 
Route class has a property _startLocation_ of type Location.
Mybatis tries to map this because the column=>property names match (implicit mapping).
But Mybatis does not know how to map Mysql POINT to Location object
That's why  you get no type handler exception for Location startLocation.
Then `select id, T_X(startPoint) as x, ST_Y(startpoint) as y`.
Alternatively, you may rename either the table column or class property to break the name match and observe the effects.

Comment: I've already removed the select * from the query statement, the no typehandler exception still exists, and it comes during project building phases, I means once I click on the build and run, it turns into failure. Furthermore if I just remove Location field from the Route object, the project runs successfully. So I'am confused that why mybatis is looking for a typehandler instead of loading the association mapper.